# Using PHP variables in document header

Tags: php, header, documents

I am trying to get php variables inserted into the code below. When the document download pop up shows up it shows $filename instead of the actual file name.  How can i achieve this?

code:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename');
header('Content-type: $type');
readfile('$filename');
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using single quotes.  Variables inside string literals using single quotes are not evaluated. Use concatenation or double quotes instead.

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); // double quotes
header('Content-type: ' . $type); // concatenation
readfile($filename); // no quotes needed
?>
```

[See the PHP manual page for the String type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: it works but now i get this error:  Couldn’t open the file. It may be corrupt or a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.

Comment: @KPO Well, you'll have to figure out what you're sending wrong, then. That's a different question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need quotes here, just use

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-type: '.$type);
readfile($filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `"`, not `'`, to get variables' values instead of names. When you use `"`, variables are parsed (to parse array elements it is required to use { and }, but I'm sure you'll find it out when you will need it).

Answer (score 1):

Use double-quotes: `"` instead of single quotes: `'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `"` quotes. PHP doesn't substitute variables in a string enclosed in `'` quotes.